# set Label a String which is in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to set UILabel.text a string which is located into coredata, but I get an error which says:`Instance member "test1" cannot be used on type 'ProfileViewController' did you mean to use a value of this type instead?` any solutions?

```swift
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
                request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
                do {
                    let result = try context.fetch(request)
                    for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                        test1 = data.value(forKey: "username") as! String
                  }
                } catch {
                    print("Failed")
                }
    }
    var test1 = String()
    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = test1  //error is here
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26)
        label.textColor = .white
        return label
    }()
```

Comment: Do you have only one user in Core Data?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to refer to `test1` when you create the label. The `text` property of a `UILabel` is an optional string, so not assigning a value is perfectly legal.

Even if you could/did assign `test1`, it won't help you achieve what you want since `UIKit` doesn't work with bindings; assigning a new value to `test1` in `viewDidAppear` won't change the value in the label.

You also need to add your `nameLabel` to the view controllers `view` and either set some constraints or set its `frame`; I will assume you have done this in `viewDidLoad` but not shown that here.

All you need is:

```swift
let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26)
    label.textColor = .white
    return label
}()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request) 
        if let result = result as? [NSManagedObject] {
        for data in result {
            self.nameLabel.text = data.value(forKey:"username") as? String
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed")
    }

    super.viewDidAppear(animated) // Don't forget to call super
}
```

If you did want to keep the name in a property, then you could implement a pseudo-binding with a `didSet` function:

```
let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26)
    label.textColor = .white
    return label
}()

var name: String? {
    didSet {
        self.nameLabel.text = name
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request) 
        if let result = result as? [NSManagedObject] {
        for data in result {
            self.name = data.value(forKey:"username") as? String
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed")
    }

    super.viewDidAppear(animated) // Don't forget to call super
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    test()                                 // run the func here 
}


func test() {
    var test1 = String()
    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = test1  //error is here
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26)
        label.textColor = .white
        return label
    }()
}
```

Comment: It didn't, The error is the same

Comment: @Billy what if you make a function and run the function in viewwillappear? like how i edited the answer

Comment: Now test1 will always be ""

Comment: Yes dont do that uuse the code i put in my answer dont set it to "" anymore.

Comment: Yes you do by doing String() and using a local variable.

Comment: You don't want to create the label in `viewWillAppear` anyway; you will end up with multiple labels if the view controller appears more than once.  Create the label in `viewDidLoad` and then fetch your data from Core Data and assign it in `viewDidAppear`